# HttpResponse's content's length doesn't match the plain text

Tags: c#, httpresponsemessage

I'm making a post request with HttpRequestMessage/HttpResponseMessage. Everything is okay, I'm getting the response into a string whose length is correct as expected, but if I want to display the raw string, it just returns one question mark character (?) and nothing else, as if the output is just one/two characters of length.

I've tried to decode the string to UTF8, still the same.

Here is my code:

```cs
var targetUrl = new Uri("https://www.targetUrl.com/");
var postData = GetPostData;
var request = httpClientHelp.GetRequest(HttpMethod.Post, targetUrl, postData);
var response = Await httpRequestProcess.SendAsync(request);
var data = Await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
Debug.WriteLine(data.Length); // Correct, i.e. 5686
Debug.WriteLine(data); // Just displays "?"
```

//. Here is the SendAsync function from the httpRequestProcess class:

```cs
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage requestMessage)
{
    var response = await Client.SendAsync(requestMessage);
    return response;
}
```

[Here is the raw string result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NTOYK.png)

[Here is the difference between the string content and its length](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hk0Ji.png)

If I copy that question mark, the output is a multiple set of unknown characters, example: � �

Comment: Try with `Convert.FromBase64String(data);`

Comment: It seems like youre getting the bytes length not the string characters length. 
Or is such a long string?

Comment: It doesn't work, Anant. It messes up with the string and throws an exception.

Comment: It's a really long string. The length of the string matches with the response I anticipate.

Comment: I think it's exactly the result Fiddler displays before decoding the response: http://prntscr.com/opizvi/direct But how do I decode it the way Fiddler does? What type of encoding is this?

Comment: Try data.Result.

Comment: Basically I captured the traffic and tried to mime the request exactly the way fiddler does, the result is the same, but Fiddle manages to decode the output, meanwhile my string is purely unknown characters. But I'm confused of why calling the .length returns the correct unencoded length.

Comment: @AnilGoel It's literally the same thing, haha. It doesn't work, unfortunately.

Comment: @Ebi-ツ Do you have access to the data you are sending. Can you post it?

Comment: It seems like fiddler is not decoding it properly also, isnt it?

Comment: @JesúsNarváezTamés This is the output by default in Fiddler, I'd have to click the "Response body is encoded. Click to decode" button, and then fiddler will decode it.

Comment: I have found this somewhere to get the encoding of the charset, maybe helps you  ´var encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(response.CharacterSet);´

Comment: @AnilGoel The data is mainly formed out of personal info, I cannot share it, unfortunately.

Comment: Which .Net version are you using ?

Comment: @Ebiツ Is it possible that data being send is in byte array. Try reading it as byte array and then convert it to string.

Comment: @JesúsNarváezTamés 4.7

Comment: @AnilGoel http://prntscr.com/opje77/direct

Comment: can you check in fiddler if this data is compressed, by any compression algo for ex Gzip ?

Comment: @SachinVishwakarma It doesn't show any, it seems that the default compression is set to none.

Comment: @SachinVishwakarma I solved the issue. Will update my thread right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @SachinVishwakarma I was able to solve the issue. The default encoding on the header was "gzip, deflate, br" as shown in Fiddler. All I had to do was initialize the HttpClient with a HttpClientHandler whose AutomaticDecompression property was optimized for  all the compression methods.

Example:

```cs
    var _httpHandler = new HttpClientHandler() { CookieContainer = new System.Net.CookieContainer(), AutomaticDecompression = System.Net.DecompressionMethods.GZip | System.Net.DecompressionMethods.Deflate | System.Net.DecompressionMethods.None };
    var _httpClient = new HttpClient(_httpHandler);
```

Thank you guys for helping me out!